# Put Blade form into a JavaScript script tag

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5.1, how do I get a Blade form into a JavaScript script tag?

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/sms/create', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
```

Comment: Changed grammar and formatting, removed tag. I would recommend that you add a bit more information to your post, however. It's currently a bit thin on information for anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Give an `id` to your form and then you can access the form like any other element using `java-script` or `jQuery`

```
 {!! Form::open(['url' => '/sms/create', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'form1']) !!}
```

for example using `jQuery`:

```
$('form[id="form1"]')...
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just like you write php code into javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var html= "{!! Form::open(['url' => '/sms/create', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}";

$("#table-shipping").after(html);
</script>
```